# How to get data from request Nodejs

Tags: node.js, null, request

Code:

```
    function getpage(link){
    var data = [];
    var options = {
    method: 'GET',
    uri: link,
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + new Buffer("c64f80ba83d7cfce8ae74f51e263ce93:").toString('base64')
    }
    };
    request(options, function (err, response, body) {
       console.log( body );
       data.push(body);
    });
    return data;
}
console.log(getpage('https://docs.google.com/feeds/get_video_info?formats=ios&mobile=true&docid=0BxG6kVC7OXgrQ1V6bDVsVmJMZFU'));
```

But data returned in Dev Console is `null`. What is that I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please explain, what you are trying to do here and what do you think went wrong ?

Comment: i want get data body from https://docs.google.com/feeds/get_video_info?formats=ios&mobile=true&docid=0BxG6kVC7OXgrQ1V6bDVsVmJMZFU

Comment: It seems that data in given link is binary. If it is text/json data then you can use like this in jQuery
`$(<selector>).load(<url>);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

request will give you a result in future. Its Asynchronous and handle it that way.

**First approach would be using callback function as-**

```
  function getpage(link, callback){
    var options = {
    method: 'GET',
    uri: link,
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + new Buffer("c64f80ba83d7cfce8ae74f51e263ce93:").toString('base64')
    }
    };
    request(options, function (err, response, body) {
       callback(body);
    });
}
```

getpage('your link', console.log); // calling function with callback;

**second approach, use promise (suggested and easy)**
use `Request-Promise` or `Axios` library then-

```
var rp = require('request-promise');
rp('http://www.google.com')
    .then(function (htmlString) {
        // Process html...

    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        // Crawling failed...
    });
```

Comment: var body = getpage('your link', console.log); how to work? sr console.log(body);